# How do I automatically sort my files in Finder (hidden files included)

Tags: macos, finder

I want to sort all my directories automatically (not freely moving), similar to the / (Macintosh HD) directory, where when I turn on hidden files, all of them are automatically sorted by name.

So, like [image]

rather than
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click and press `Sort By` -> `Name` or use `View` -> `Sort By` -> `Name`.